# Can I use a DataGridView in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, service, datagridview, data-binding

I created a Windows Forms app that generates reports and it works great. It binds a bunch of DataTables to a bunch of DataGridViews, exports the resulting display to a bitmap, and everyone is happy. I would like to create a service that generates these reports automagically instead of having to run each report by hand in my Forms based app. I am running into a problem where I have a DataTable with rows in it, but when I assign it to be the datasource for one of my DataGridViews, the number of rows in the DataGridView remains at zero.

Here is a snippet of relevant code where I am binding this data (yet it is not updating):

```
DataGridView testGrid = new DataGridView();
testGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;

for (int i = ServerTableDay.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
testGrid.DataSource = ServerTableDay[i];
}
```

The test grid always has zero rows no matter which table I try to bind by using the .DataSource =

What am I missing, or is this even possible in a Windows Service?

Comment: I think you are talking about Windows Forms, not Windows Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your heading - No you will not be able to use a DataGridView with a Windows Service because this is a User Interface control and the Windows Service would have no UI control. That being said you might look into writing your output to a logfile if you want to keep track of it.

As for your current winforms setup issue try -

```
if (ServerTableDay.Count > 0) {
     testGrid.DataSource = ServerTableDay;
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking to have it visible to a user, just have it visible on a "console" kind of way so I can draw it to a bitmap. Since it's a service, does this mean it will never "draw" anything even if its invisible?

Comment: The best I've come up with so far is what you've come up with. As in it won't work.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is for you to generate an HTML page that you can pull up and look at if formatting is what you are looking for. I don't think I've ever used the Drawing capability from a Windows Service - in theory it should work if you are creating a bitmap.

Comment: I just figured out a ghetto way of doing it. I added a Windows Form to my service project, and added my controls to that. the problem is that I can't format the controls at all, but I can draw to a bitmap!

Answer (score 1):

Although not ideal, you can use a DataGridView inside a Windows Service (just reference System.Windows.Forms). I just tested in Service app, and it works fine. I say "not ideal" because there's a lot of overhead that comes with a DataGridView, most of it being that the control is really a visual control, which isn't needed in a Windows Service application.

The real question is: What type of object is ServerTableDay? It's not a System.Data.DataTable (like you allude to), because you can't access the index (e.g. ServerTableDay[i]) of a DataTable like that. Also, verify in debugging that there is data in your ServerTableDay object.

Comment: That's what I referenced, but I wasn't able to put rows into it. ServerTableDay is a List<DataTable> where I collect a bunch of tables and add it to various DataGridViews that I loop through. The snippet doesn't make it clear, but I omitted a bunch of the loop stuff for clarity. Works great in a WinForms app. I verified that rows are present in the ServerTableDay index I was referencing, but the rowcount for the GridView neved moves?

Comment: This also helped me convert a Winforms app to console.

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
testGrid.DataSource = ServerTableDay;
```

I don't think you need to do a loop. Actually you musn't do a loop. Just tell the datagridview that its datasource is your datatable.

Comment: I had the loop because I had a list of many datagrids that I was binding to many datagridviews. Even if I did a one datatable to single gridview, I still have no rows?